# Question Regarding Binary Subarrays With Sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sliding-window, sub-array

I was interested in finding a solution to a problem that provided a binary array called *nums* - which, for example, could consist of 10101, or 00000, or any such combination of 0 and 1's - from this, we had to devise a program that would return the number of non-empty subarrays with a sum *goal*...

The particular question I'm referring to can be found here.
https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-subarrays-with-sum/

In particular, I was interested in understanding the following solution:

```
class Solution {
    public int numSubarraysWithSum(int[] nums, int goal) {
        // answer is # of subarrays with sum at most goal - # of subarrays with sum at most (goal-1) 
        return cnt(nums, goal) - cnt(nums, goal-1);
    }
    public int cnt(int[] nums, int S) {
        int n = nums.length, sum = 0, res = 0;
        for (int l = 0, r = 0; r<n; r++) {
            sum+=nums[r];
            while (sum>S && l<=r) {
                sum-=nums[l];
                l++;
            }
            res += (r-l+1);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

While I am able to grasp the logic included in `cnt` - which is standard logic for a *sliding window*, I am unable to grasp the reasoning behind the logic presented in `numSubarraysWithSum`. It seems as though the original poster is computing the count of subarrays that would add up to the goal, and then computing the count of subarrays that would add up to the goal-1.. I am unable to grasp the purpose of doing this, as I originally thought that `cnt(nums, goal)` should return the answer expected by the entire problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the comment more closely: "...sum *at most* goal".  If you take the count of subarrays with *at most* goal, and subtract the count of those with *at most* goal-1, you are left with those whose sum is *exactly* goal.

Answer (score 1):

the function cnt(num, goal) return the number of subarrays l, r where sum(l, r) <= goal.

So to get the number of subarrays where the sum is exactly goal, we can exclude the subarrays where the sum <= goal-1,

In set theory words we can say:

let S1: be the set of subarrays where sum(l, r) <= goal.

let S2: be the set of subarrays where sum(l, r) <= goal-1.

let S3: be the set of subarrays where sum(l, r) = goal.

then S1 = S2 U S3.

and S3 = S1/S2 (because S2 and S3 has no intersection).

and card(S3) = card(S1)-card(S2).